# Failed to construct async operation in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to use parallel instead of waterfall to do an operation.

I used mongoose and I have a method of a model like this

```
module.exports.updateStatus = function(task_id, status, callback){
    Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: task_id}, 
        {$set: {status}},
        {upsert: true,'new':true},
        callback)
}
```

Then why am I getting unexpected token at line 2?

```
async.parallel([
    Task.updateStatus(id, status, (err, resp), callback) => {
        callback(err, resp)
    },
    Credit.addCredit(user_id, 10, (err, resp), callback) => {
        callback(err, resp)
    }
], (err, resp) => {
    if(err){
        return handleError(err, 'Failed to update task status', res)
    }

    res.json({
        success: true,
        result: {task: resp}
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, async parllel receives array of functions, each function has a callback, that needs to be passed to the function, and will be called once the current function will finish.

You are trying to call the functions, where you need to pass an array of tasks so each task will call the functions, and you are passing the parameters wrong to those tasks. please check the documentation [async parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) and find the example below.

```
async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            updateStatus(id, status, callback)
        },
        function (callback) {
            addCredit(user_id, 10, callback)
        }], (err, resp) => {
            if(err){
                return handleError(err, 'Failed to update task status', res)
            }
            res.json({
                success: true,
                result: {task: resp}
            })
    });
```

Comment: what if I have error in updateStatus? will addCredit execute?

Comment: If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main callback is called immediately, with the error. If you wish to continue, you may want to use async each, and decide if to call the callback, with the received error.

Comment: so my error handle is correct? Why some people is doing try catch and throw new Error()?

Comment: If you will get an error from one of the tasks the handleError will be called, and res won't be returned, if this is what you want, then this is right. Sometimes it is not current function responsibility to decide what to do with the error so you just rethrow it to the callee until someone handles it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the invalid part:

```
async.parallel([
    Task.updateStatus(id, status, (err, resp), callback) => {
        callback(err, resp)
    },
    Credit.addCredit(user_id, 10, (err, resp), callback) => {
        callback(err, resp)
    }
]
```

You're giving it two callbacks at once, try:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) { Task.updateStatus(id, status, (err, resp), callback) }
    function(callback) { Credit.addCredit(user_id, 10, (err, resp), callback) }
]
```

Instead, where we're taking the callback parameter from the async function.